# Arithmetic operations on file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Given a file containing numeric data in the following syntax:

```
D1
D2
--
D3
D4
--
...
--
Dn-1
Dn
```

Where `Di` is any positive number. 
I would like to output a new file containing

```
D2-D1  
D4-D3  
...  
Dn-Dn-1
```

What is the base way to achive this using bash?

Comment: Are D1 and D2 separated from D3 and D4 by '--' in the input ?

Comment: Yes, they are separated by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having this source file:

```
$ cat source
3
7
--
9
14
--
9
3
```

Using `awk` (better tool for this task):

```
awk '{print $2+0-$1+0}' RS='--' source > target
```

Result:

```
$ cat target
4
5
-6
```

If you want to stick to `bash`:

```
flag=0
while IFS='' read -r num; do
   if [ $flag -eq 0 ]; then
      d1=$num
      flag=1
      continue
   fi
   if [ $num = "--" ];then
      flag=0
      continue
   fi
   (( num -= d1))
   echo $num
done < source > target
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU ***awk*** solution:

Sample `testfile` (assuming `D` prefix is mandatory):

```
D2
D3
--
D3
D5
--
D3
D10
--
```

---

The job:

```
awk -v RS='--' -v FPAT='[0-9]+' 'NF{print $2-$1}' file
```

The output:

```
1
2
7
```